# Contract has no network id set, cannot lookup artifact data

Tags: web3js, truffle, ganache, truffle-contract

I am using web3 v1.0.0-beta.37 and truffle contract for server.js configuration. I have defined two contracts `FlightSuretyData.sol` and `FlightSuretyApp.sol` FlightSuretyApp contract access functions from FlightSuretyData without importing the contract but through the FlightSuretyData deployed address. I have tried producing many steps through online research but I am not able to figure out the solution to this:

Here's my deploy_migrations:

```
const FlightSuretyApp = artifacts.require("../contracts/FlightSuretyApp.sol");
const FlightSuretyData = artifacts.require("../contracts/FlightSuretyData.sol");
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(deployer) {

    let firstAirline = '0x55690752ed06B1d37510D20B3516b2D12F007f6d';

    deployer.deploy(FlightSuretyData, firstAirline)
    .then(() => {
        return deployer.deploy(FlightSuretyApp, FlightSuretyData.address)
                .then(() => {
                    let config = {
                        localhost: {
                            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:7545',
                            dataAddress: FlightSuretyData.address,
                            appAddress: FlightSuretyApp.address,
                            numOracles: 50,
                        }
                    }
                    fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/../src/dapp/config.json',JSON.stringify(config, null, '\t'), 'utf-8');
                    fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/../src/server/config.json',JSON.stringify(config, null, '\t'), 'utf-8');
                });
    });
```

Here's my server.js configuration:

```
import FlightSuretyApp from '../../build/contracts/FlightSuretyApp.json';
import FlightSuretyData from '../../build/contracts/FlightSuretyData.json';
import contract from 'truffle-contract';
import Web3 from 'web3';
import express from 'express';
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");


let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'));
const accounts = web3.eth.getAccounts();
web3.eth.defaultAccount = "0x55690752ed06B1d37510D20B3516b2D12F007f6d";
let flightSuretyApp = contract(FlightSuretyApp, FlightSuretyApp.address);
let flightSuretyData = contract(FlightSuretyData, FlightSuretyData.address);

class ContractServer {

  constructor() {
    this.flightsForPurchase = [];
    this.flightsLanded = [];
    this.oracles = [];
    this.status = [20, 30, 40, 50, 0];
  }

  init = async () => {

    flightSuretyApp.setProvider(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'));
    flightSuretyData.setProvider(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'));

    try {
      const address = await flightSuretyApp.address;
      const accs = await accounts;
      await flightSuretyData.methods.authorizeCaller(address).send({from: accs[0]});
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.toString());
      console.error('Check if Ganache is running and contracts deployed properly!');
      process.exit();
    }
```

I have tried truffle `migrate --reset --development`

Here's the error produced:

> Error: FlightSuretyApp has no network id set, cannot lookup artifact
>   data. Either set the network manually using
>   FlightSuretyApp.setNetwork(), run FlightSuretyApp.detectNetwork(), or
>   use new(), at() or deployed() as a thenable which will detect the
>   network automatically. Check if Ganache is running and contracts
>   deployed properly!

Comment: what is the point of this code : flightSuretyApp.setProvider(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'));
    flightSuretyData.setProvider(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'));
?

Comment: @MajdTL was just trying out set provider manually. ‍♀️

Comment: how does your truffle config file look like? and why manually ? will await web3.flightSuretyData.me........  not work?